# Spring Boot - Source must not be null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a simple Spring Boot app with one endpoint that creates a new record in a `users` table.

However, when i hit this endpoint with Postman, i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
```

What is the issue?

**EDIT:**

Apparently it does save the record in the DB, but returns an error still.
Here's the code for `UserController`:

```
    @PostMapping
    public UserRest createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) 
    {

        UserRest result = new UserRest();
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userDto);

        UserDto createdUser = userService.createUser(userDto);

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(createdUser, result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What do you have in line 45 of UserController.java?

Comment: `BeanUtils.copyProperties(createdUser, result);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java spring has asserting that parameter can't be null.
So as you mentioned you are calling method

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(createdUser, result)    at com.demo.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
```

You simply need to make sure that values are not null

If you look in source of copy method you will find check for not to be null.

```
Assert.notNull(source, "Source must not be null");
Assert.notNull(target, "Target must not be null");
```

Comment: What parameters?

Comment: @Gambit2007 i assume both createdUser and result must not be null.

Comment: @Gambit2007 in your case message say Source so looks like your createdUser property is null

Comment: Oh ok, got it, let me check.. (also i edited the question if it helps)

Comment: @Gambit2007 could be that you userService.createUser(userDto); is not returning user properly or what

Comment: Ok, i'm stupid.. (and new to Spring). 
`createUser` was returning `null`... thanks for clarifying!!